# Is it possible to show directions and locations to estimote beacons from Android App?

Tags: android, ibeacon, estimote

I have been working with Estimote Beacons for Android App Development. I'm getting beacons range and distance from Android. But, i want to show the directions and location of specific beacon to the user to reach specific beacons. So, **is it possible to show the direction and location of beacon in Android app to reach to specific beacon?**

Comment: are you using this: http://estimote.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I am using that.

Comment: You can use Estimote Indoor Location SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Getting directional information to a beacon is much, much more difficult than simply getting a distance estimate.

A beacon by itself does not provide any directional information.  It is simply a radio transmitter with which you can use the strength of the signal to get a rough estimate of the distance.

It is possible to do full indoor location of a mobile device using multiple beacon transmitters at known locations.  Only if you know the specific location of the mobile device vs. the location of beacons can you do what you suggest. Doing this, however, requires sophisticated custom software, non-trivial site surveys, and beacon locations that do not change.

Several companies offer systems that do this, but none are free or open source, and it most certainly is not a core beacon feature.

Comment: Thank you @Wouter! Can you tell those companies/APIs offering this. I am interesting to know more about this case.

Comment: Estimote has an Indoor Location SDK and if you buy 4 estimotes, you can see it working with their app for iOS

Comment: Is it possible the same for Android?